# how do I lookup code generated by annotation

Tags: java, annotations

I'm trying to figure out what's going on behind the scene of one framework based on annotation. And I'm just wondering if I can lookup code generated using this annotations without compiiling and decompiling. It would be grate if there is some plugin for IDE (IntelliJ IDEA prefered as I'm working with Android Studio) that allow to navidate to it with single click like goto implementation of method.
Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by 'code generated by annotation'. If you want to figure out what's happening.. You should start at annotation processor..

Comment: Not all annotation generate codes, few annotation do actually. eg. [lombok](http://projectlombok.org/). Annotations are metadata of class, so you can analyze them using [reflection](http://www.journaldev.com/721/java-annotations-tutorial-with-custom-annotation-example-and-parsing-using-reflection). If you want to know how framework run with annotation, you should check its annotation processor like @KVK said.

Comment: @KVM I mean exactly what you are talking about. But as `javac` now behaves like `apt` (by including JSR269) I asked "without compiiling and decompiling" (read manually).
So basicly I'm asking about tools that make life easier.

Comment: @Nickolas I know that RetentionPolicy is CLASS so they are processed on compilation time